# UITableView, clicks, mimic button pressed

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am working with UITableview, I want the cells to look like a pressed button, how can I do that?

Comment: Create a custom UITableView cell and use whatever control want in it.

Answer (score 1):

try this ,

// get selected tableview cell and perform some animation on cell. i am using scale up and down animation

```
 #pragma mark Table View Delgate method
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tbView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  CustomTableViewCellForTradeList *cell=(CustomTableViewCellForTradeList *)[tbl_TradeList cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath ];
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.85,0.85);
    [self performSelector:@selector(NavigateToTradeBuySellAfterScaling:) withObject:indexPath afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

// rescale uitableview cell.

```
-(void)NavigateToTradeBuySellAfterScaling:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CustomTableViewCellForTradeList *cell=(CustomTableViewCellForTradeList *)[tbl_TradeList cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath ];
cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0);
[self performSelector:@selector(NavigateToTradeBuySellAfterScaling1:) withObject:indexPath afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

//navigate to other view controller

```
 -(void)NavigateToTradeBuySellAfterScaling1:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 TradeBuySellViewController*  tradeBuySellController    = [[TradeBuySellViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TradeBuySellViewController" bundle:nil :entity];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tradeBuySellController animated:YES];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the background view of `UITableViewCell` when clicked. You can get the clicked cell with this method.

```
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```